# Сравнение хешей строк

Tags: строки, хеширование

Допустимо ли делать выводы о равенстве содержимого строк на основе равенства их хешей?

Comment: Я не поняла вопрос. Наверное, из-за слов "равенстве" и "содержимого". :) Если хеши совпадают, это не значит что строки равны.

Comment: Ну бывает :D вы прочтите еще раз, вдумайтесь..)

Comment: Так я пытаюсь, не получается. :)))

Comment: Ну смотрите, Angelina, строки можно как сравнивать, вызвав функцию strcmp к примеру, правильно? strcmp побайтно сравнит обе строки и выдаст нам некий результат (равны, не равны, первая меньше второй и т.п.). А можем эти строки прохешировать, получить коротенький хэш, а поскольку, если используемая хэш-функция генерирует достаточно уникальные хеши (низкий процент коллизий), хэш будет короче строки (которая может быть очееень длинная), быстрее делать выводы о равенстве строк на основе хешей!

Comment: И все бы ничего, только вот написанная с использованием данного алгоритма программа безбожно глючила и выдавала слова, которых и вовсе нет.

Comment: Хоть и низкий, но процент всё же есть. Я бы не рискнула. :) Это всё равно, что сравнивать равенство строк по количеству символов. :)

Comment: Да ну нет, не все равно) В вашем случае процент промахов будет куда больший, уж поверьте мне:)

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда по длине строк и по трём символам взятых в случайных местах строки. :)))

Comment: Подобрать два одинаковых хэша будет труно, но если вам это удастся, то браво, вы нашли коллизии!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В общем случае, хэширование не является взаимно однозначным отображение, то есть нельзя утверждать, что две разные строки дадут два разных хэша. Возьмем для примера MD5 хэш. На вход поступает строка произвольной длины. На выходе - хэш длиной 128 бит. Таким образом, на входе бесконечное множество, а на выходе - конечное. Очевидно, что в бесконечном множестве найдется бесконечное количество строк, которые дадут один и тот же хэш.

Comment: То есть использование данного метода строго говоря является ненадежным

Comment: Строго говоря, нет, не является надежным. Но практически вероятность коллизии исключительно мала. То есть Вы можете считать, что при равных хэшах, исходные строки с высокой степенью вероятности совпадают.

Comment: Строго говоря, да, в общем случае бесконечных множеств достоверный результат даст только полный перебор.

Comment: Если говорить не о *криптографических хэшах,* а о хэшах типа `hashcode()`, то утверждение про исключительную малость вероятность коллизии, разумеется, неверно. Возьмите, например, в `Java` строчки, имеющие 256 одинаковых первых символов и `N` различных символов потом - они все будут иметь одинаковый дефолтный хэш. **(наврал :)**

Comment: Во всех хэш-функциях существуют коллизии. Криптостойкой же функция считается, если подобрать коллизии максимально трудно.

Comment: @Котик\_хочет\_кушать, странно, документация это [не подтверждает](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29). Хэш строки вычисляется как полином от всей строки, а не только первых 256 символов.

Comment: @northerner, здесь многое зависит от используемое хэш-функции.

Comment: @northerner Спасибо, что проверили - и впрямь ошибся. Просто где-то на `stackoverflow` читал, что в какой-то из реализаций `JDK` *(видимо, не очень известной)* для `String.hashCode()` применялся метод, который учитывает только 256 символов. Попробую поискать.

Answer (score 6):

Нет, однозначно на основе сравнения кешей можно говорить о неравенстве объектов при неравенстве кешей. Совпадение кешей говорит о вероятном равенстве кешируемых объектов, поэтому нужно проверять их равенство непосредственно.

Comment: Иными словами, равенство Хэшей строк - необходимое (но не достаточное) условие равенства самих строк, а прямое сравнение - необходимое и достаточное.

Answer (score -5):

Конечно. Равенство хэшей означает бинарную эквивалентность содержимого строк. Естественно, для лексикографического сравнения хэши не подойдут.

---

Учитывая комментарии о коллизиях, отмечу, что хэш-функция должна быть тщательно выбрана.

Comment: Мм, ну если бинарно совместимы, то наверняка и лексикографически тоже, правильно?